# error when configured application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

This is my web.config file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration> 
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">     
    </authentication>               
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When i trying to host my application getting error..

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that app pool is set up with asp.net 4.0
make sure the website (or virtual directory) in IIS is an application, and not just a folder; right-click will give you related options